# Materialize Create and Open Modal

Tags: materialize

I wan't to create a Modal with Materialize and Open it with a Button click. I used the code from the Modal page but it is somehow not working. Maybe someone can help.

I know some guys posted a similar question but none of them is answering my question.

Comment: Please accept questions on SO when people take the time to answer you. If they are not the correct answer, tell them so.

Comment: @Micheal Hi Michael, I am sorry i haven't seen your answer. But it is correct i solved it the same way. Thanks

Comment: For materialize css v0.98.2 http://stackoverflow.com/a/43773050/4143613

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the modal example to work with a button to trigger the modal you'll need initialize the button using JavaScript. Be sure that you have included both jQuery, and both JavaScript and CSS from materialize—see the [getting started guide](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html).

To initialize the modal (or all modals) you'll invoke the `leanModal()` method on it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
```

> The "href" attribute of `.modal-trigger` must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered.

Example modal button:

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Click to open modal</a>
```

This button would open a modal with the id `modal1`.

See this <kbd>[code pen](http://codepen.io/mblarsen/pen/JXPRjY)</kbd> for a working example.

Comment: While trying this am getting error leanModal is not defined

Comment: @vimalkumar in the codepen I linked to or your own code? (the codepen runs fine, just tested it)