# How I can open a materialize modal when a window is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I want to open a modal window when the user be in a window, I mean, open a modal without a trigger button, I have this example.

```
<button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger" id="btn-1">Modal</button>
<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
<div class="modal-content">
  <h4>Modal Header</h4>
  <p>A bunch of text</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
</div>
```

It works if I click on the trigger button, but I don't want a click.
I use this code when the window is ready:

```
$(function()
{
    function checkCode()
    {
        $("#btn-1").click();
    }
});
```

This automatically push the button and make the effect that modal is auto opened, but I don't want to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution in materialize.js
We must use:

```
$(".MyModal").openModal()
```

to open modals and:

```
$(".MyModal").closeModal()
```

to close it.
Materialize team forgot refresh their documentation.

Answer (score 16):

For Materialize v0.98.2

Create a modal

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Open modal when a document ready load

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal').modal();
    $('#modal').modal('open'); 
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

Pure JavaScript solution.

```
const elem = document.getElementById('modal id here');
const instance = M.Modal.init(elem, {dismissible: false});
instance.open();
```

Answer (score 6):

you can do that :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.modal1').modal('open');
    });
```

Comment: You can also use the $('yourModal').modal('open') function on every event top open  'yourModal'

Comment: I've tried that, but I receive an error:
$(...).modal() is not a function
:(
I had to use $(...).leanModal()

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with `instance.open()`.

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var Modalelem = document.querySelector('.modal');
            var instance = M.Modal.init(Modalelem);
            instance.open();
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still having problems given the other solutions, I had to nest the jQuery('#modal_id').modal('open') statement in a second document.ready statement like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#modal_id').modal();
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery('#modal_id').modal('open');
      });
});
```

I don't know why this works, and I know it's just plain ugly, but it works so..

Comment: i see this is the issue with materialize js components. You need to initialize the components separately.

Comment: @BilalAhmad can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this is working for me

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#modal1').modal('open');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine which event makes sense to trigger the modal to be displayed.  `onload` or `onmouseover` may work for you instead of `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

First, You must initialize the modal:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modal-bill-order').modal();
    $('#btn-bill').on('click', function () {
        $('#modal-bill-order').modal('open');
    });
});
```

And then with the help of the action of a button you execute that this modal be opened